# Sorting very long json object with php

Tags: php, json

I am working with an API and i am trying to sort the json object it returns to me. Here is a small cut out of the json object

[image: Here is a small cut out of the json object]

Now i want to sort this because i only want to save part of the data. Say i wanted to save the "_ID" here. THe data i need is really way further down but i think if i can figure out how to get this, i can figure out the rest. Since as you can see from the picture, it contains many objects inside objects and arrays within arrays its very confusing for me to target the specific values i want

I have tried something like this:

```
    $body = $response->getBody();

    $data = json_decode($body, true);

    $sortedData = $data."hits".hits[0]."_id";


    return $sortedData
```

Also tried without the quotation marks, but i cant really get it to work. Im very new to PHP.

Comment: Your syntax makes no sense, whether with or without the quotation marks. The dot is only the concatenation operator in PHP, it does not have a second meaning to allow property access like it does in JavaScript.

Comment: yusorude could you explain how to do then instead of just saying what ive done is wrong? I know its wrong.. Thats why im here

Comment: I know that’s why you’re here, but were you _should be_ instead IMHO, is a beginner’s tutorial that explains such _basics_ … // You decoded these _objects_ into associative arrays, so `$data['hits']['hits'][0]['_id']` should be the correct way to access that element.

Comment: Very good. Lead with that next time. If you want to add it as an answer i can mark it correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You decoded these objects into associative arrays, so `$data['hits']['hits'][0]['_id']` should be the correct way to access that element.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php explains the basics of how to work with arrays and access elements within them.

Comment: Now i have something like this for another element `$capital = $data['hits']['hits'][0]['_source']['Vrvirksomhed']['attributter'][4];`
Now i cant be sure that the value i want is always going to be at position 4 of the "attributter" array. Can i target the spot in the array that has the type of "kapital" somehow?
Bit hard to explain. The array looks like this https://imgur.com/a/gTmvY5r

Comment: The first 4 positions of the array have a different type than "KAPITAL"

Comment: In that case, loop over the `attributter` structure, and check what the `type` key of the current item contains. `foreach($data['hits']['hits'][0]['_source']['Vrvirksomhed']['attributter'] as $item) { if($item['type'] == 'KAPITAL') { /* do stuff with $item */ } }`

Comment: This was perfect for the "KAPITAL" part, but i get an error when i try the same with this part `foreach($data['hits']['hits'][0]['_source']['Vrvirksomhed']['deltagerRelation']['organisationer']['medlemsData']['attributter'] as $item) 
            { 
                if($item['type'] == 'EJERANDEL_PROCENT') 
                { 
                    $ownerPercentage = $item;
                   
                } 
            }`
https://imgur.com/a/ADpIa62

I get an error around "organisationer" for some reason. Shouldnt it be exactly the same as for the "attributter" in the first one?

Comment: `deltagerRelation` is an array again, so you either need to access an element directly via its index, `$data['hits']['hits'][0]['_source']['Vrvirksomhed']['deltagerRelation'][0]['organisationer']`, or – loop again at that level, if you don’t know which item you are looking for. Same for the properties on the following levels, `organisationer`, `medlemsData` are arrays as well.

Comment: Okay, so a foreach in a foreach in a foreach? Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Depends on whether you need to loop over an unknown number of elements at a given level, or if there can by only ever be one, resp. you know which position you are looking for.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196523/discussion-between-mike-nor-and-misorude).

Answer (score 1):

Since php 5.5, you can use [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) to get specific column from the array :

```
$body = $response->getBody();
$data = json_decode($body, true);
$sortedData = array_column($data, '_id');
return $sortedData;
```

**Edit**

From what I see on your array sample, you want to do a recursive multidimensional arrays search (not just 2-dimensional).

Assuming you have array like this :

```
$arr = array(
  array(
      'x' => '10',
      'name' => 'blah',
      'other' => array(
        '_id' => '26',
        'color' => '10x',
        )
  ),
  array(
      'x' => '7',
      'name' => 'blahblah',
      'other' => array(
        '_id' => '29',
        'color' => '7x',
        )
  ),
  array(
      'x' => '15',
      'name' => 'blahblahblah',
      'other' => array(
        '_id' => '27',
        'color' => '15x',
        )
  ),
  array(
      'x' => '1',
      'name' => 'sdf',
      'other' => array(
        '_id' => '41',
        'color' => '1x',
        )
  ),
  array(
      'x' => '4',
      'name' => '3dgdg',
      'other' => array(
        '_id' => '31',
        'color' => '4x',
        )
  ),
  array(
      'x' => '5',
      'name' => 'nmnmnm',
      'other' => array(
        '_id' => '36',
        'color' => '5x',
        )
  ),
  array(
      'x' => '21',
      'name' => 'dhshshhh',
      'other' => array(
        '_id' => '34',
        'color' => '21x',
        )
  )
);
```

And you want to get the `_id` key. In that case you could try this function :

```
function array_column_recursive(array $haystack, $needle) {
    $found = [];
    array_walk_recursive($haystack, function($value, $key) use (&$found, $needle) {
        if ($key == $needle)
            $found[] = $value;
    });
    return $found;
}
```

Usage :

```
$ids = array_column_recursive($arr,'_id');
sort($ids);

print_r($ids);
```

Reference :

1. [array_column](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php#119954)
2. [array_column_recursive](https://github.com/NinoSkopac/array_column_recursive)

Comment: This returned an empty array. Also, the json object has many objects inside of it, with many different arrays. How do i target a specific one?